# Add word to custom taxonomy slug in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks, taxonomy

I want to add a specific word to every taxonomy archive.

I've this domain:

http://example.com/brand/nike/

And I want it to look like this:

http://example.com/nike-shop/

Is there any way to add the word "shop" to the slug and remove the taxonomy name (brand)?
I've checked to codex but I couldn't find anything.

**EDIT:** Changed the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using your custom taxonomy, you can try to add `rewrite` parameter to the code, like this:

```
register_taxonomy('taxonomy',
    array('post'),
    array(

        ...

        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'taxonomy-archive'
        )
    )
);
```

But once you change your code, do not forget to go to Settings-Permalinks and just click Save Changes button there.

If you can not affect on the `register_taxonomy()` function, you can try the solution based on this tutorial https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/remove-taxonomy-slug-from-urls.html

Comment: sorry, my question was not clear. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: ok, then the tutorial is just for you - use it to remove "brand" from URL, after that you can rename "nike" to "nike-shop" in /wp-admin/